# Linker error in iOS build when including static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I am working on importing a static library on our company's project. While I see so many questions on this topic, I tried all of them and none solved my problem.

Here is what I tried.

1) I have added the libraries in Build settings -> Link Binary with libraries. The static libraries are there.

2) I added the path of the static libraries ( They are fat static libraries for armv7, armv7s & arm64 ) in Search paths.

3) I tried turning on/off Build Active Architecture only.Valiant.

I am very new to iOS development and would be grateful with some help. Right now, I am just trying to import the library and build it. I have attached screenshots of my settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that library is calling c++ functions (std::new, std::string, etc.)  You need to link to the C++ standard library.  You can do this by by going into your project's build settings and look for "C++ Standard Library" and set it to libc++

Comment: Why would it prompt me for these things now when I was already using the C++ functions?

Comment: Which c++ functions are you using?  Perhaps a build setting got changed inadvertently? Build settings can be applied at the project level (i.e. applied to all targets) or overridden at the target level to be specific to that target.  If you look in the build settings you should see in the "Resolved" column what setting is being applied for the project or target selected in the Build Settings sidebar.

Comment: I've been using delete,new,string etc. And I am overriding these in the target level.I just figured out it was the shell script that is causing this. Without the shell script it builds fine, though i am not sure if it works.